# Bash script removing files unexpectedly

Tags: bash, mv

I have this script that I'm running to rename all the files in a folder to "1.png", "2.png", etc, but sometimes it will completely erase (or move the file somewhere else, I have no idea what's happening) the first 10 or so images. This seems to happen whenever there's more than 10 images inside the folder. The script I'm running is below, anyone have any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1"
cnt=1
for fname in *
do
if [ "$1" != '/var/www/cydia.stumpyinc.com/theme/images/browse/icons/' ]
then
    mv "$fname" ${cnt}.png
    cnt=$(( $cnt + 1 ))
fi
done
```

**EDIT**

I'm also getting this error in the terminal, don't know if it's important or not though

```
mv: cannot stat `*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: In general, a good debugging tip is to put `echo` in front of your "action command" (in this case the `mv` line) so that the script will just print out what it would do instead of actually doing it.

Comment: you are getting the mv: cannot stat `*: No such file or directory` because the directory is empty.  Your rename script is super bizarre.  Check out the correct way of doing it below.

Comment: Thanks so much as I did not know that was possible, and I've debugged it and found out what the problem was. Do you know how to add leading zeros to the beginning of `$cnt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is bizarre: from your description the correct way of renaming everything to a number should be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash


error() {
    ec=$1
    shift;
    echo "$@" 1>&2
    exit $ec
}

TARGETDIR="$1"

if [ ! -d $TARGETDIR ] ; then
     error 1 "$TARGETDIR: No such directory"
fi

if [ "$TARGETDIR" = '/var/www/cydia.stumpyinc.com/theme/images/browse/icons/' ] ; then
     error 1 "Cannot process $TARGETDIR"
fi

# Okay let's process stuff now...


cd $TARGETDIR
if [ "$(echo *)" = "*" ] ; then
     error 1 "$TARGETDIR: empty directory"
fi

# calculate zero-padding for the number of files present.

zeros=$(ls -1 | wc -l | wc -c)
cnt=1
for k in * ; do 
    if [ -f "$k" ] ; then
          ext=."$(echo $k | awk -F\\. '{ printf $NF }')"
          fn=$(printf "%0${zeros}d" $cnt)
          echo "Converting $k to ${fn}${ext}"
          mv "$k" "${fn}${ext}"
          cnt=$(($cnt+1)) 
    fi
done
```

Comment: Woah nice , that worked pretty good, I had to tweak it just a bit to work with leading zeros, but other than it worked perfectly, thanks so much

Comment: Not sure where your edits went so i modified above to add correct number of leading zeros to files in a directory. A couple of things about the zeros variable: 1) the `-1` is not really required for `ls` but it clarifies the intent (and yes it's minus one not minus el in this case :-)); 2) the code will scale, as you add new files to the directory you can simply rerun the script there and it will repad everything.